# How do I get spacemacs web-mode autocomplete to relax a little?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, config, spacemacs, company-mode

I'm new to Spacemacs and Emacs. When I'm editing in web-mode, like an html document, I'm often triggering the autocomplete prompt when I haven't typed anything relevant yet. I don't have this problem in the html blocks, that I remember, but when in script (js) or css blocks it gets pretty cumbersome to have to swat away the menu constantly.

[image: autocomplete suggestions triggered by semiconlon]

You can see from the above example that I'm editing css and after completing the property definition with a semicolon the autocompletion pops up meaning that hitting semicolon and enter to start the next line will instead add useless text to the line after the semicolon. how can I alter this behaviour?

[image: Similar behaviour inside a script tag]

You can see here again I have almost the same problem when editing inside the script tag. Opening a function definition with a curly brace and hitting enter to go to the next line instead inserts useless text after the brace.

The file I am editing is .svelte, but I've told emacs to use web-mode

My dotspacemacs/user-config has the following:

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-visual-line-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.svelte?\\'" . web-mode))
(setq web-mode-markup-indent-offset 2)
(setq web-mode-css-indent-offset 2)
(setq web-mode-code-indent-offset 2)

(setq configuration-layer--elpa-archives
      '(("melpa-cn" . "http://elpa.emacs-china.org/melpa/")
        ("org-cn"   . "http://elpa.emacs-china.org/org/")
        ("gnu-cn"   . "http://elpa.emacs-china.org/gnu/")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a spacemacs user myself, but it appears you have set `company-minimum-prefix-length` to 0, whereas you probably want it to be at least 2.  You could also consider increasing `company-idle-delay` which would cause candidates to be presented slower.

Comment: maybe spacemacs loads and configures company in a somewhat different way, in either case I couldn't get the above config to have any effect, maybe not in the right place. So tried to find spacemacs specific info and got here [https://develop.spacemacs.org/layers/+completion/auto-completion/README.html] . None of that did what I needed either, except disabling return key completion.

Comment: you can just evaluate `M-:` `(setq company-minimum-prefix-length 2)` from your html buffer to test.  I'm assuming you're using `company-mode` for autocompletion, ie. if you evaluate the value of `M-:` `company-mode` is `t`, in which case you should post the value of the active `company-backends` in your html buffer as well (Note: if spacemacs overrides `M-:`, that is equivalent to `M-x eval-expression`)

Comment: That is helpful. I apparently need to set the variable in a different place. I had added `(setq company-minimum-prefix-length 1)` to .spacemacs in the user-config function, but this did nothing. I'm at a loss as to where I am supposed to put it though. Evaluating the expression directly from the html buffer as you suggest works fine. Now that i understand the problem better I see that [This question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53110/for-spacemacs-how-do-i-override-a-layers-setting-company-minimum-prefix-leng) is essentially the same

Comment: well, normally, one would set those company variables globally -- but if you want a special value for just `html-mode` (or `web-mode`), you would set a `(setq-local company-minimum-prefix-length ...)` in your `html-mode-hook`.  Spacemacs probably has a user-configurable mechanism for setting mode hooks, otherwise you should just be able to setup a hook per usual

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to emacs also. I think this is the same question as

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53110/for-spacemacs-how-do-i-override-a-layers-setting-company-minimum-prefix-leng

Basically it's because of this fucntion in `.emacs.d/layers/+lang/html/func.el`

```lisp
 (defun spacemacs//company-web-minimum-prefix-length ()
    "Set company minimum prefix length to 0 for the current buffer only."
    (set (make-local-variable 'company-minimum-prefix-length) 0))
```

related to https://github.com/osv/company-web/issues/4

You could change the minimum length to some value other than 0

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` section of your spacemacs file `spc + fed`

```
     (auto-completion :variables
                      auto-completion-enable-snippets-in-popup t
                      auto-completion-return-key-behavior nil
                      auto-completion-tab-key-behavior 'complete)
```